# navigate panel in Jira software

Tags: jira

A [tutorial](https://youtu.be/TsG3OWTDAFY) shows Jira like this

[image]

My Jira shows like this

[image]

I am running **JIRA Agile v8.8.1** on my own device

How do I navigate to the panel pointed out by red arrow?